# Gradle in the mac's idea, build sync failed

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, gradle

Created a gradle project with idea2017 for mac, when refresh all gradel projects, build:sync failed

java version: 1.8.0

gradle version: 4.4

[Error: Could not find or load main class .Library.Java.JavaVirtualMachines.jdk1.8.0_152.jdk.Contents.Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsdcu.png)

How can I build it?

Thanks.

---

[I have already set JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH9QJ.png)

---

Comment: You need to setup JDK in Intellij. Basically there is no `JAVA_HOME` for Gradle to build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Yes, I have  already set JAVA_HOME